# Force NFS directory information update

Tags: linux, cache, nfs

Is it possible for a non-root user to force an NFS client to update the information it holds about a directory tree? My problem is that I want to do the following:

1. Run a big compilation job (via LSF) on some box "A". This generates a load of binary files, which are written to a directory on a file server. This is all done over NFS.
2. Run some sort of test script or follow-up job which uses these shiny new binary files. This script runs on box "B", which views the same directory using NFS.

The problem seems to be one of caching. Suppose that `foo/bar.o` is created by step (1). When step (2) runs, `ls foo` might well not show `bar.o`. It's possible to mostly work around this by sleeping for (say) thirty seconds and hoping that the cache will automatically update but... yuck. And sometimes it doesn't work!

What I'd love to do is issue some command saying "Yes, I don't care if this makes access to `foo` slow, but please double check the directory entries". I can see that this might allow a user to degrade other users' performance, so I would understand if this requires root privileges. If so, is there any other way that I can guarantee that the script on (2) sees the new files?

In case it's relevant, the client boxes are all running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, which uses a kernel based on version 2.6.18 (which presumably also determines the version of the NFS client)